Angular Date Picker - Issue with focus lost on the input field
I am trying to do some validation on Angular Material Date picker on (focusout) event on the input field. If there is an issue found during validation I return the focus back to the Mat Date Picker Input field.
At the same time I don't want the validation to be called when user selects the date picker icon to open the date picker popup. Is there a way to avoid calling the validation done on (focusout) when clicking the date picker icon.

<mat-form-field>
<mat-label> select dates </mat-label>
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="seldatepicker" [(ngModel)]="seldate" (focusout)="validateDate($event)">
<mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="seldatepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #seldatepicker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

Thanks in advance .
I tried using (dateChange) event to check for validations but that does not prevent from calling validation on date inputs on Input element when clicking on Mat date picker icon.

You can use the updateOn property of ngModelOptions configuration and set it to validate only on blur event.

If above suggestion does not help, then you can subscribe to closedStream which fires on close of datepicker, then with a setTimeout  function, we trigger the datepicker open method after a delay of 500ms.
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.picker.closedStream.subscribe(() => {
    debugger;
    if (this.modelRef.invalid) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.picker.open();
      }, 500);
    }
  });
}

Ideally you should place this in a directive to promote code reusability.
Full Code:
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {
  MatDatepicker,
  MatDatepickerModule,
} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { provideNativeDateAdapter } from '@angular/material/core';

import { Directive, Input, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { JsonPipe } from '@angular/common';
import {
  NG_VALIDATORS,
  Validator,
  AbstractControl,
  ValidationErrors,
  FormsModule,
  NgModel,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appCustomValidator]',
  standalone: true,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomValidatorDirective),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class CustomValidatorDirective implements Validator {
  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    let today: Date = new Date();

    if (new Date(control.value) > today) return { LessThanToday: true };

    return null;
  }
}

/** @title Basic datepicker */
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-overview-example.html',
  standalone: true,
  providers: [provideNativeDateAdapter()],
  imports: [
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    FormsModule,
    JsonPipe,
    CustomValidatorDirective,
  ],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class DatepickerOverviewExample {
  @ViewChild(NgModel) modelRef!: NgModel;
  @ViewChild(MatDatepicker) picker!: MatDatepicker<any>;
  selectedDate = new Date();

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.picker.closedStream.subscribe(() => {
      debugger;
      if (this.modelRef.invalid) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.picker.open();
        }, 500);
      }
    });
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

Hello , with the above example I still end up triggering the validation on handkey entries for input field when opening the date picker.  For now i have created a flag on (opened) event of datepicker and checking this flag at my (focusout) event before validation starts inside the setTimeout method .Thanks for your inputs .
